# How to check if the event.target is equal to a specific component?

Tags: angular

I have a ExampleFormComponent that uses the tag `<example-form-component>`, and a DialogBoxComponent with the tag `<dialog-box-component>`. I am capturing keyup events in the DialogBoxComponent and I want to do some action if the event.target is `<example-form-component>` specifically.

Code:

```
export class DialogBoxComponent {

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    @HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event'])
    handleKeyPressEvent(event) {

        // how can I check if event.target is ExampleFormComponent?

    }
}
```

Comment: maybe `instanceof` is what you need ? `if (event.target instanceof ExampleFormComponent) { // something }`

Answer (score -1):

The 'keyup' `event.target` is going to return you the element that has focus when the event is fired, otherwise the root element of your DOM.

Accordingly, if your DialogBoxComponent has the focus when the 'keyup' is fired, then your `event.target` is going to be the DialogBoxComponent.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup) is the MDN doc on 'keyup'.

Check [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5z6jrs?file=app%2Fapp.component.html), look on the console when firing the event with and without focussed button.